# Как узнать сгенерированный адрес файла в JS

Tags: javascript, html, url

Если у элемента взять значение атрибута:

```
$('script').getAttribute('scr')
```

То мы получаем относительный адрес. Например, 'common/sample/sample.js'
Но если мы ищем адрес через:

```
$('script').src
```

Адрес показывается полный: 'http://your.site/common/sample/sample.js'
И вот вопрос: можно ли имея строку path - относительный адрес, получить ее полный? Естественно без костылей.

Comment: Если способ `$('script').src` работает, то что мешает его использовать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы путаете понятие "значение атрибута" с "абсолютным путем".

В значении атрибута может быть как абсолютный так и относительный путь. В случае если указан абсолютный путь, то данные берутся с него напрямую:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

// возьмет данные с https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com
```

если же указан относительный путь, то данные берутся с корневого адреса ресурса:

```
<script src="/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

// возьмет данные с http://your.site
```

Итак, если вы попрежнему хотите получить абсолютный путь имея относительный, то достаточно просто объединить строки:

```
const relativeToAbsolute = (url) => (url.includes("://")? url: `${window.location.origin}/${url}`;

const url1 = $('script').getAttribute('scr');
const url2 = $('script').scr;

/** 
* В обоих случаях ниже путь будет абсолютным
*/
relativeToAbsolute(url1);
relativeToAbsolute(url2);
```